# How to run a python script in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, console, child-process

So I know how to run console commands in javascript, I'm doing that like this:

```
        child_process.exec('ls', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("child processes failed with error code: " +
                err.code);
        }
        console.log(stdout);
    });
```

But as soon as I insert a python script, this stops working and I have no idea why. Do you guys have any ideas, why it doesn't work with python commands, like "sudo python ...." I just copy paste the line, which works in my console without javascript and in my script it looks then like this:

```
        child_process.exec('sudo python....', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("child processes failed with error code: " +
                err.code);
        }
        console.log(stdout);
    });
```

I think the path shouldn't be relevant for this, so I just replaced it with some dots.

Comment: If that worked it yould be a serious security issue in my opinion. Also @epascarello is right.

Comment: Why would you run the python script via `sudo`?

Comment: How are you running the Java Script?

Comment: The javascript is in a websocket handler, so that I can execute my script with another device and I'm not sure about whether sudo is needed or not, but it isn't the problem here, I tried it both ways with and without sudo :) The complete code is getting served via an nodejs server on a raspi btw.